# In Go, is it possible to assign a variable to someArray[someIndex] without needing an asterisk to dereference?

Tags: arrays, pointers, go, alias, slice

This works:

```
pressure := &dataDump[845]
CurrentPressure := *pressure
```

But is there a way to change the first line so that `pressure` is an alias for `dataDump[845]` and so no asterisk is needed:

```
CurrentPressure := pressure
```

Comment: Remember that Go tries to be obvious and avoid surprising the programmer. Secret pointers are arguably rather surprising.

Comment: That maps and slices are already secret pointers is bad enough.

Comment: You can create a slice, but that's not any better: pressure := dataDump[845:846];  currentPressure = pressure[0]

Comment: Go's pointer stuff works pretty much like C's does modulo pointer arithmetic and the Tour of Go describes this pretty well. Remember that Go has strict rules for assignability of different types.

Comment: Why the downvote? How could I improve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For "changing" data

By "changing" data I mean if the `dataDump` array / slice changes, you want your `pressure` to reflect the changes.

This is not possible in Go. What you want would require to explicitly specify the memory address where a variable is to be created / placed.

Your best option is to use a pointer which you included in your question.

Another alternative would be to create a function, e.g.:

```
function pressure() int {
    return dataDump[845]
}
```

And using it:

```
currentPressure := pressure()
```

### For "static" data

If `dataDump` doesn't change once it's acquired, then this is not a problem. You can use a simple non-pointer variable like this:

```
pressure := dataDump[845] // Not a pointer to the element but a copy of it
```

And then:

```
currentPressure := pressure
```

But then in this case `currentPressure` isn't even needed, you can just use `pressure` (or maybe name it `currentPressure` in the first place).

### Using memory layout

I don't know how you acquire your data, but in some cases it is possible to provide the Go value where you want the data to be placed / unmarshaled. Such cases may be reading the data from a file, or from a TCP connection.

If this is you case, you may use a `struct` carefully planning the memory layout of the data you get, and then you may use struct fields which you can declare to be non-pointers.

Example:

```
type dataDump struct {
    _ [845]int32 // Some unused data

    pressure int32
}
```

If you can "unmarshal" your data into a value of this struct, then you can obtain the current pressure like this:

```
dump := dataDump{}
// Unmarshal into dump
currentPressure := dump.pressure
```

If you go down this way, be aware of the [Spec: Size and alignment guarantees](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees). Care must be taken due to implicit alignments!

See related questions for more details about laying out memory:

[Why use arrays instead of slices?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30705048/1705598)

[Why have arrays in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645175/why-have-arrays-in-go)

Comment: Thanks, heaps for a great answer - looks like the "Using memory layout" method is the way to go. I'll do more reading. Just a question; I'm not familiar with the syntax of "_ [845]int32" which reserves the memory, do you have a link to the docs please?

Comment: @DavidSmith `_` is the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier). It is used if syntax requires an identifier, but you don't want to use the result. You could just use a real field name instead of that, e.g. `data [845]int32`.